# Cannot get background image to display properly

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to line up four background images to make up a side menu panel with four text links overlaying each. Presuming background-image is the best way to do this, I am applying the background image to each text area. What I'd like to know is, is there anyway I can get the background image to display full size so that I can then align my text to the correct place.

PAGE LINK: http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=4600

Here's the CSS I have tried applying to the first two text areas:

```
.boxera {
 background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads
/2014/11/NULEFT-A.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boxera p {
margin-top: 4.000em;
margin-right: 1.000em;
margin-left: 12.500em;
}

.boxerb {
 background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads   
/2014/11/NULEFT-B.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boxerb {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -1.800em;
}
```

And the last two text areas I've tried putting in specific dimensions, but with the same result.

```
.boxerc {
 background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads 
/2014/11/NULEFT-C.png');
background-size: 16.000em auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boxerc {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 12.500em;
}

.boxerd {
 background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads
/2014/11/NULEFT-D.png');
background-size: 29.688em 20.250em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boxerd {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 26.500em;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this. I've tried looking this up, it all seems straightforward until I put it into practice!

Comment: You can use a background image, but you need to give the element the proper height and width to match your image sizes.  I would just use inline images and position your text absolutely on top of them.  This will enable you to more easily create a responsive design.

Comment: I did give height and width dimensions to the fourth text area - boxerd - but I am still getting the same result ? I'll probably use the images as you suggested but surely background images can't be this awkward to use.

Answer (score 0):

I added height and width to boxera and it resized the image.

So for example

add the corresponding image sizes to:

```
div.wpb_text_column.wpb_content_element.boxera
div.wpb_text_column.wpb_content_element.boxerb
div.wpb_text_column.wpb_content_element.boxerc
div.wpb_text_column.wpb_content_element.boxerd
```

so for boxera

```
height:295px; width:475px;
```

This is the only way I can think of actually altering the background image as you've rapped it so deeply in divs. Unless as mentioned you strip it out of CSS and into some image tags thats the only other way around it I think.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm using a Wordpress theme along with a drag and drop plugin. As you and jme11 have mentioned using measurements, is there any way to ensure responsiveness when using background images, when background-size: 100% 100% doesn't work and using responsive units such as the ems used above don't seem to work either ?

Comment: Ah ok. As far as I know and I could be wrong here, using a background-image linked to a div would be limited by whatever dimensions you set within it. Sorry it's not the answer your looking for!